# Make player object freeze / become non-interactive when text pops up

Tags: c#, gui, unity-ui

I have a Dialogue system that shows up when a scene starts or a player touches an object. I am wondering if is it possible to make the player freeze/not interactable when dialogue pops up. I don't think I can use freeze time with `Time.timeSacle = 0;` since I am using animation it will freeze the animation and won't play. Is there a workaround this?

This is my Dialogue Manager

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text nameText;
    public Text dialogueText;
    public Animator animator;

    private Queue<string> sentences;

    public static DialogueManager instance { get; private set; }

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;    
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
        dialogueText.text = string.Empty;
        sentences = new Queue<string>(); 
    }// end of start

    public void StartDialogue(Dialogue dialogue)
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsOpen", true);
       // Debug.Log("Starting conversation with " + dialogue.name);
        nameText.text = dialogue.name;
        sentences.Clear();  

        foreach(string sentence in dialogue.sentences)
        {
            sentences.Enqueue(sentence);
        }

        DisplayNextSentence();
    }

    public void DisplayNextSentence()
    {
        if(sentences.Count == 0)
        {
            EndDialogue();
            return;
        }

         string sentence = sentences.Dequeue();
         StopAllCoroutines();
         StartCoroutine(TypeSentence(sentence));
         

         Debug.Log(sentence);
    }// end of Display next Sentence

    IEnumerator TypeSentence (string sentence)
    {
        float i = 0.07f;
        dialogueText.text = "";

        foreach(char letter in sentence.ToCharArray())
        {
            dialogueText.text += letter;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(i);
        }
    }

   void EndDialogue()
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsOpen", false);
        
       // Debug.Log("End Of Conversation");
    }
}
```

To play the dialogue in a new scene I am just calling an instance to Start dialogue and passing my dialogue in it

Comment: Your dialog manager could communicate with your playerController and simply set a bool in the playerController that currently no input is processed

Comment: If the behaviour of your player object is what you want to change, then you should show us how the player object and it's scripts are set up. Also note that you can play animations in unscaled time if you want them to continue while time scale is set to zero.